# Evaluate Expression within awk

Tags: awk

I want to create a conditional expression string and pass in an awk script. My script is as below...

```
comm="\$3 == "hello""
awk -F "^T" -v command="${comm}" '
{
  if ( command )
  {
    print "hye"
  }

  if ( $3 == "hello" )
  {
      print "bye"
  }
}' test
```

But the statement "if ( command )" always evaluates to true which is not correct. I want to know the correct way of executing this statement..

On Running...

```
./test_awk.sh
```

It returns

```
hye
```

Which is not the expected answer.

Test file has following ( just a sample ):

```
hello^Thye^Tbye
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You want to use the pipe notation and `getline` for getting output from external commands, see [this manual page](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fVariable_002fPipe.html#Getline_002fVariable_002fPipe) for example. BUT depending on what you are trying to do, which is not clear from the example, this might not be the way to go.

Comment: I am trying to evaluate the conditional expression within awk.. My expression is "\$3 == hello" and the modified script is                                                       comm="\$3 == "hello""
awk -F "^T" -v command="${comm}" '{
    if ( command )
    {
        print "hye"
    }

    if ( $3 == "hello" )
    {
        print "bye"
    }
}' test     The file considered is test. If the 3rd field in file test is hello, the conditional expression shud evaluate to true. which is being passed in variable "comm" above.. Please help

Comment: Please add this information together with a sample `test` file to the question by using the [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/523085/edit) function,

Comment: Could you post awk --version?

Comment: [tf_hmmsc_am@chi-m3-int-jump1]$ type awk
awk is hashed (/bin/awk)

Comment: Can anyone suggest a way to do this as this is a blocker rite now for my project....

Comment: your command returned `$3 == hello` and both of your if is the same as one if but with different `"print "`. it look likes two same if condition. `if ( $3 == "hello" # value of command )
  {
    print "hye"
  }

  if ( $3 == "hello" )
  {
      print "bye"
  }`

Comment: Hi Kasiya, My requirement is to pass a string expression to the awk script like "if ( command )" in the above example... I do not want to explicitly specify a condition like "if ( $3 == "hello" )". But the problem is the condition "if ( command )" always returns true and hence prints the value "hye" which is not correct. I need something to evaluate this conditional expression successfully and generate the result true / false based on execution...

Comment: Any suggestions ???

Comment: I suggest you rethink your approach - for example using a here-document so that the shell expands your variable expression before passing it to awk.

Comment: Thanks but could you suggest as to how to implement the here document and what approach would be better in this case

Comment: I guess that characters following the = are interpreted as if they appeared in the awk program preceded and followed by double quotation (") character, in other words, as string value. You didn't answer my question about awk --version, it is important to know if you are using GNU or POSIX version of awk and it's version :)

Answer (score 2):

If the logical operation is always the same (i.e. in this case `==`) and you just want to change the field number and the value against which it is tested, then you can pass them as separate variables e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -v field=3 -v value="hello" '
{
  if ( $field == value )
  {
    print "hye"
  }

  if ( $3 == "hello" )
  {
      print "bye"
  }
}' test
```

If you truly want to create a variable awk script, then IMHO a different approach is required, for example using a *here document* to write the awk script on the fly using the shell to expand your command variable - something like

```
#!/bin/bash

mycommand="\$3 == \"hello\""

awk -f- test << EOF 
{
  if ( ${mycommand} )
  {
    print "hye"
  }

  if ( \$3 == "hello" )
  {
      print "bye"
  }
}
EOF
```

Comment: Probably this is the right approach, awk consider value in `-v var=value` as string and do not parse "$3 ==". According to manual `if (expr)` return true if `expr` is a string not empty.

Answer (score 0):

#### Lets trace:

```
$ cat test
hello^Thye^Tbye

$ awk  '{ print ($3 == hello) ? "true" : "false" }' test
true # wrong output

$ awk  '{ print ($3 == "hello") ? "true" : "false" }' test
false # correct output
```

according to trace when we use `$3 == hello` we get wrong output and when changed to `$3 == "hello"` including with **double quote around the string** the output is correct.

So we found the wrong statement and the problem is on `comm` variable value if you set:

```
$ comm="\$3 == "hello""
```

and take echo:

```
$ echo $comm
```

you will see the comm variable has below value in it

```
$3 == hello
```

so you need **double quote around the value** then edit your value with this one:

```
$ comm="\$3 == \"hello\""
$ echo $comm
$3 == "hello"
```

then go and improve your's. hope this helps.

Comment: @KaisyA, did you test your suggestion? Problem is related to "$3" that is not evaluated inside awk, isn't it?

Comment: @Letizia I traceed that for myself and when I forget double quote I get wrong result.